# Freemarker - call external java function with page number as parameter

Tags: java, css, templates, freemarker

I have Freemarker templates for generating pdf documents, that can have multiple pages based on variables content. I need generate unique code on each page, the generating logic takes page number as parameter. I have working utils class, callable from template used for dates formatting etc.
Ideally I would like to be able call my utils class like that, with something that would provide current page number on each page (simplified example):

```html
<h1>Utils result: ${utils.generateUniqueNumber(pageNumber)}</h1>
```

I will probably need to place this code into header/footer, to achieve have it on each page.

Currently I have working page counter in footer defined using css:

```html
<head>
    <title>RESEA - Selection Notice OWCMS</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    
    .page-counter:before {
       content: "Page "counter(page)" of "counter(pages)
    }
    </style>
</head>
```

Then used in footer , works as expected.

I'm not sure if actual paging is driven by Freemarker or CSS, so maybe I need to make CSS call my utils function.

Any advise, or relevant study source is welcome!

Comment: Pagination can't be done by FreeMarker itself, as it just generates text, like HTML. Pagination is done by whatever generates PDF from HTML+CSS, or the browser if you print a HTML page. So I think your best bet is doing it with CSS.

Comment: I'm not too experienced with CSS, can there be a way to call java utils class passed in Freemarker data model from CSS? Or call external logic in different way from CSS? I will need to work with DB during unique page code generation, so I need execute logic, ideally in java service that is performing Freemarker generation.

Comment: Ah, I believed CSS itself supports generating page numbers... but now I see `@page` etc. was never widely implemented. Although, if you generate PDF (or anything with XSL-FO) there's still hope for something like that. But if you have to do the pagination yourself, and hence the page numbering too, then CSS is irrelevant. Saw some people do some JavaScript hack for client-side pagination in the browser.